# Filter finds nothing when top is too low

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I expect that `top` will limit the number of results returned after they are filtered (as it is e.g. in SQL).

However, it is not working for me in Microsoft Graph API at least for chats.

```
await graphClient.Chats.GetAsync(rc =>
{
    rc.QueryParameters.Filter = "members/$count eq 1";
    rc.QueryParameters.Top = 50;
    rc.QueryParameters.Expand = new[] { "members" };
})
```

This query will return one item. However, when I decrease the `top` parameter to e.g. `1`. It will return nothing.

Is it a bug or I am doing something wrong?

If it is just an "unexpected" feature, where it is documented?